# Click an element automatically when you click on another element. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive to click on an item and can later be edited. This directive is called click-to-edit. I'm doing an ng-repeat, and every row is an accordion. My idea is to cick the edit button, and I can edit the text, as if I clicked on it.

[image]
how can I do it?

```
     <uib-accordion close-others="true">
     <div ng-repeat="faq in faqs">
        <div class="col-sm-11" >
          <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="faq.open">
              <uib-accordion-heading  >
                  <span  ng-click="ignoreClick($event);" ><a  href='' click-to-edit  ng-model='faq.pregunta'   typeinput='textarea' >{{faq.pregunta}}</a></span> <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': faq.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !faq.open}"></i>
              </uib-accordion-heading>
              <span click-to-edit   ng-model="faq.respuesta" >{{faq.respuesta}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"  >
          <button type="button"   class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> 
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
     </uib-accordion>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/K5fXaIzSBkV91V7AFoqw?p=preview

Comment: what is your actual *question*?  "how can I do it?" isn't descriptive enough at all.

Comment: You want the text in the 'click-to-edit' directive to be editable only? Or do you need both that and the uib-accordion-heading to be editable?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing `scope.editState = false` inside the directive, you can pass it in from your controller.

Set up your directive to take `editState` as a parameter:

```
scope: {
    model: '=ngModel',
    editState: '='
}
```

Create an `editState` variable on each `faq` in your controller, with a function to toggle it:

Controller:

```
$scope.faqs=[
    {"pregunta": "pregunta1", "respuesta": "respuesta1", "open":true, "editState": false},
    {"pregunta": "pregunta2", "respuesta": "respuesta2", "open":false, "editState": false},
    {"pregunta": "pregunta3", "respuesta": "respuesta3", "open":false, "editState": false}
  ];

$scope.toggleEditState = function(index) {
    $scope.faqs[index].editState = !$scope.faqs[index].editState;
}
```

Controller's template:

```
<a click-to-edit edit-state='faq.editState' ... >

<button ng-click="toggleEditState($index)"></button>
```

Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/S4OllJV64EYFNo6WIjVH?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you, I do not quite understand what you mean, I tried and it did not work for me.

Comment: I added a plnkr.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it, but in any button when I click, only the element of the first accordion is edited. I need to edit the element corresponding to the button, and it would be great if it appeared to edit both the header and the content of the accordion.

Comment: Right, we'll need an `editState` variable for each faq. Please check again.